# How to create/end run loop to properly deallocate memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, sskeychain

In my ARC iOS app I am running a for loop that ends up with a large memory allocation overhead. I want to somehow end my for loop with minimal/no extra memory allocated. In this instance I am using the SSKeychain library which lets me fetch things from a keychain. I usually just use autorelease pools and get my memory removed properly but here I don't know what is wrong because I end up with 70 mb + of memory allocated at the end of the loop. I have been told that I should start/end a run loop to properly deal with this. Thoughts?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSError *  error2 = nil;
                SSKeychainQuery*  query2 = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
                query2.service = @"Eko";
                query2.account = @"loginPINForAccountID-2";
                query2.password = nil;
                [query2 fetch:&error2];
            } 
}
```

Comment: AutoreleasePool should purge all memory used in between. Maybe `SSKeychainQuery` has memory leaks? Profiler is your friend here.

Comment: Nah I checked and after lengthy chat with the developer I think SSKeychainQuery is fine. I think the problem is with how I structure my code. Do you know how I could make my query here fall out of scope? Insert it into its own .m file, call an instance of this .m from another class, nil the instance after this? Something like that?

Comment: Check with profiler and see what allocations you get and where they originate from. Maybe keychain reserves some memory for cache or something. It's very trivial to profile this bit.

Comment: Update: Tried playing with allocations instrument for quite some time, it doesn't always show the same result as the memory report in xcode. Very weird.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to measure memory usage?

Results of a *very* simple test...

Running in the simulator, measure only resident memory before and after.

Without autoreleasepool...
Started with 27254784, ended with 30212096, used 2957312

With autoreleasepool...
Started with 27316224, ended with 27443200, used 126976

Obviously, the autoreleasepool is preventing memory from growing too bad, and I don't see anything close to 70MB being used under any circumstance.

You should run instruments and get some good readings on the behavior.

Here is the code I hacked and ran...

The memchecker

```
static NSUInteger available_memory(void) {
    NSUInteger result = 0;
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    if (task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&info, &size) == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        result = info.resident_size;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the code...

```
#define USE_AUTORELEASE_POOL 1

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSUInteger beginMemory = available_memory();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
#ifdef USE_AUTORELEASE_POOL
            @autoreleasepool
#endif
            {
                NSError *  error2 = nil;
                SSKeychainQuery*  query2 = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
                query2.service = @"Eko";
                query2.account = @"loginPINForAccountID-2";
                query2.password = nil;
                [query2 fetch:&error2];
            }
        }
        NSUInteger endMemory = available_memory();

        NSLog(@"Started with %u, ended with %u, used %u", beginMemory, endMemory, endMemory-beginMemory);
    });

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I used the memory report from the simulator to evaluate memory as I ran my app off of my phone. With your code I got the following output without autorelease pool: "Started with 49410048, ended with 135876608, used 86466560". This is in line with my memory report showing a bleed of 70 + mb. Without autorelease pool "Started with 48824320, ended with 135892992, used 87068672". Hmm.... Perhaps this has something to do with how I imported the SSKeychain files manually.

Comment: I downloaded SSKeychain again from here -> [link](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain). I implemented it by dragging the SSKeychain and SSKeychainQuery m & h files into my project and didn't mess with anything. Where do you call this code? App delegate? I want to figure out what I did differently from you.

Comment: @MasterCrouch - Didn't follow your first comment as it seemed you would talk about with/without autoreleasepool, but both said without.  For your second comment, the second code snippet is the complete implementation of the AppDelegate's  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. -- Also, I simply installed the library using carthage.

Comment: Whoops. With autorelease --> "86466560", Without autorelease --> "87068672"

Comment: Ok. The code you wrote works well in the simulator but bleeds a lot on an iPhone. When you put this code on an actual phone you see the ~80 mb bleeding I am talking about. Can you test your code on an iPhone and verify?

Comment: Update: Tried playing with allocations instrument for quite some time, it doesn't always show the same result as the memory report in xcode. Very weird.

Comment: So what's in this 70M of leaked memory? Can you check in Instruments what library allocates it and what kind of stuff is there? I don't believe this chunk of code can produce a leak.

Comment: Can't attach a device at the moment.  You should get a full instruments run while on the device to see what's going on.  Also, note that the call I showed is just a glance into the resident set, which may or may not go down as memory is freed.